# Uso de condicional en preguntas y puntuación

Tags: gramática, puntuación, condicional

¿Una de las siguientes frases es más correcta que la otra?

1. Te ganas $5000 en la lotería. Tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados. ¿Lo haces?
2. Te ganas $5000 en la lotería. Tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados. ¿Lo harías?

¿El uso del punto para dividir en 3 oraciones está bien, o debería estar usando otra puntuación? Siento que dividirlo de esta manera es más como en inglés, y que en español las frases son más largas.

Comment: La pregunta suena mejor así: "¿Si te ganas $5000 en la lotería y tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados, lo harías?" y la respuesta es no.  :-)

Comment: @DGaleano :) Es lo que pensé, que para usar el condicional necesitarías el uso del "Si"... Por cierto, yo creo que tampoco donaría el dinero. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Soy la única a la que "te ganas" le suena horrible? A lo mejor es algo regional, pero yo definitivamente omitiría el pronombre *te*. Por cierto, la propuesta de @DGaleano me parece buena pero yo empezaría la pregunta a partir de "lo": Si ganas $5000 en la lotería y tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados, ¿lo harías?"

Comment: @Yay. Si debe ser algo regional porque por estos lados es prácticamente obligatorio. Imagino que te suena tan horrible oír **"Si te ganas la ..."** como a nosotros nos suena **"Si ganas la ..."**. Con respecto al signo "¿" estoy completamente de acuerdo en que puede ir ahí pero quisiera preguntar si como lo puse está equivocado o es tu preferencia.

Comment: @DGaleano Qué curioso, yo también acabo aprendiendo español aquí. No creo que sea *incorrecto*, pero la escritura debería imitar la pronunciación, y en este caso la entonación marcadamente ascendente se inicia a partir de "lo". Además, cuanto más corta sea la pregunta más se facilita la lectura. La pregunta es si lo harías o no; lo demás es contexto.

Comment: @Yay. Yo sí que aprendo español aquí, especialmente de tus completisimas respuesta. Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que se ve mejor usando comas (para dar a entender que se enumeran las acciones), pero en cualquier caso, con los puntos seguidos igual se ve bien.

Hay 2 opciones más y 2 opciones adicionales introduciendo el hecho imaginario del presente:

> 1. Te ganas $5000 en la lotería, tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados, ¿lo haces?
> 2. Te ganas $5000 en la lotería, tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados. ¿Lo haces?
> 3. Si te ganaras/ganases $5000 en la lotería, tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados, ¿lo harías?
> 4. Si te ganaras/ganases $5000 en la lotería, tu pareja sugiere que dones el dinero a los más necesitados. ¿Lo harías?

Depende de la entonación que quieras dar es que si deseas poner una coma al final para formular la pregunta o un punto seguido para mayor pausa.